# How to mock window.location.href in Backbone Marionette unit test?

Tags: jasmine

> I have a function that when doesn't find anything stored in the
>   cookie,redirects to some page specified as:

```
showEnrollRoute: function(){`*enter code here*`
            var username = Application.utils.getCookie("username");
            if(username != null || username != undefined){
                Application.vent.trigger("refresh:header");
                var channel = module.getChannel("counties");
                channel.then(function(channel){
                    channel.request("fetQuestions");
                }); 
            } else {
                console.log("Start");
                window.location.href= Application.getConfig("logoutSuccess");//error point
                console.log("End");
            }   
        }
```

> The window.location.href is causing the unit-tests to fail.
>
> Some of your tests did a full page reload.
>
> I did some research and found out that I've to mock $window object in
>   unit test to prevent reloading the page when running tests?
>
> Can anyone please suggest a way to go about it? Thanks in advance!
>
> EDIT: This problem is same but the question is different now. I have
>   found out that the mocking the $window object inside test-case would
>   stop the the error from happening. Can anyone please suggest a way to
>   go about it?

Answer (score 0):

The best to do this is to replace the `location.href` with a setter method provided by the location object.

Use `location.assign(<URL>)` if you want the user to be able to go back in history, or `location.replace(<URL>)` to avoid a browser history entry.

[.assign()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_assign.asp)

[.replace()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_replace.asp)

Now you're able to mock these functions in your tests. Either with a manual override or by using a mock library like [sinonjs](http://sinonjs.org/).

The test could look like:

```
it('should call correct URL', () => {
  const expected = '<URL>';

  sinon.stub(location, 'assign');

  // other setup if required

  showEnrollRoute();

  expect(location.assign).toHaveBeenCalledWith(expected);

  location.assign.restore();
});
```